# Basic Auth working but simple auth not working for create user

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I am totally stuck here in Drupal 8 REST API, any help is very appriciate.

**Problem:**

I am using Drupal 8.3.x, simple_auth module to generate Auth token for REST. When I try to create user by Authorization Bearer then its not working but when I try to create by Basic Auth then it works fine. I also enabled permission for user REST.

See Permission for user resource: URL: admin/config/services/rest/resource/entity%3Auser/edit
[image]

**Postman Data:**

Request header:
Authorization:Bearer token_value
Content-Type:application/hal+json
X-CSRF-TOKEN:OWp4RVNjlQbdjq-s6CMjNRIcfNiYsHp1L7Of87vJH2w

[image]

**In Error Log:**
League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. in League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::accessDenied() (line 165 of /var/www/html/d8/drupal-8-composer/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by giving user creation permission to anonymous user.
"Access POST on User registration resource"

[image]